# Connecting to redis using kue always creates a connection to localhost

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, kue

I can't connect to Redis using kue, I've followed this [article](http://bl.ocks.org/mojodna/1251812), practically I'm creating the connection by using the kue redis client, and the connection code is this:

```
  var kue = require('kue'),
  redis = require('kue/node_modules/redis');

  app.redisClient =  redis.createClient('6379', 'remoteip',{});
  app.redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Redis error encountered', err);
  });

  app.redisClient.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Redis connection closed');
   });

   kue.redis.createClient = function() {
      console.log('client ------------------',app.redisClient);
      return app.redisClient;
   };
```

and it seems like Kue is trying to connect to a local Redis (which I don't have installed), because I'm getting this exception:

> Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED

I've read this [post](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue/issues/54) and it seems like the issue has been resolved in version 0.8 and I'm using 0.8.11 :/,  finally I also wanted to override the client using a different client instance by using [redis nodejs](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) without any luck, because I'm getting the same error.

any help will be more than appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a different way to setup the connection and it works so far this is what I've done:

```
app.redisClient =  redis.createClient(config.redisPort, config.redisUrl,{});

app.redisClient.on('connect', function () {
    console.info('successful connection to redis server');
});

app.redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Redis error encountered', err);
});

app.redisClient.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Redis connection closed');
});

kue.app.listen(config.kuePort);

app.jobs = kue.createQueue({
    redis: {
        createClientFactory: function(){
            return app.redisClient;
        }
    }
});
```